# Rocktuner CT2 problem

Tags: tuning, acoustic-guitar, equipment

I have a problem with a piece of equipment I have. I've found in the old locker [this](http://shop.warwick.de/?&c=&lang=en&smk=1&modul=shop&site=article_details&article_id=D0851711001322750296A7724&article_category=D0566349001321517442A50638&nm=D0566349001321517442A50638%7CRockTuner) tuner, and wanted to tune my guitar with it. But after I do that, I find that my guitar is 2-3 pitches higher than it should be (I used standard EADGBE). 
This tuner has three modes: bass, guitar and wind instruments, and I assume that my problem is because the different mode is turned on. Maybe if anybody used or use this tuner, he could give a tip, how should I use it. I tried all buttons, but the mode is unchanged.

I also cannot get, how clefs (keys) are working and why they are needed, and should I set my pitch to 440?

My default screen looks exactly like on the screenshot under the link, with a letter C in the lower right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Remove the battery.**

I think it is set to some other base pitch for a *transposing* instrument, like an E-flat clarinet, so while it is probably calibrated correctly, it is not displaying the same note names as on the piano. I don't think A=440 or A=450 or some other tuning is the issue. You want to get it back into "guitar" mode.

Usually the easiest way to re-initialize this kind of electronic device to its default mode is to **remove the battery**, wait a few minutes, and put the battery back in. Try this and see if it solves the problem.

### Update:

I found a list of the features of this particular model of tuner. To wit:

[http://www.amazon.com/Rocktuner-Auto-Chromatic-Clip-On-Guitar-instr/dp/B003VKB74E](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003VKB74E)

- 3 Modes: Guitar, Bass, Wind instruments
- 4 selectable keys: C, F, Bb, Eb
- A4 calibration: from 430 to 450 Hz

The person asking the question said that the tuner is displaying 3 half-steps away from where it should be.

[image]

But A=415 is one half-step lower than A=440, and A=466 is one half-step higher than A=440. Note that this tuner can only accommodate from A=430 to A=450, which is less than a half-step in either direction. So this is clearly not what the person asking the question is experiencing.

Therefore, the problem is that the tuner is set to accommodate a transposing instrument in F, B-flat, or E-flat, like the list of features says. E-flat tuning is three half-steps transposed from C tuning.

The person asking the question needs to get his unit back to C and out of the Eb key transposition mode.

Here is how to do this:

- Hold down the button labeled "Key".
- Use the up and down arrow keys until the "Key" transposition indicator on the unit’s display, in the lower-right corner, says "C" and not "Eb" or something else.

Comment: @Wheat-an Eb clarinet ? a rare beast indeed ! However, I think you're probably in the right direction, as this tuner can be set in different 'keys'(clefs), so maybe an Eb on an alto would show as a C on the tuner.

Comment: @Tim - you are right, Wheat has it backwards. Electronic tuners always show concert pitch; they *never* transpose. The OP did not say *how* he was using the tuner. If he's not tuning DI with a jack, he can't really count on an accurate reading from the tuner's small microphone. If using the microphone, readings will be inconsistent. That said, removing the battery definitely can't hurt.  While you're at it, I would take it a step further and put in a fresh one as well.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - I certainly wouldn't advocate using the mic., but the DI or the vibration sensor should do the job well. OP stated acoustic gtr. so maybe no DI.

Comment: @Tim - the mic is ok for wind instruments. Contact mics can be problematic as well - you have to place them on the correct part of the instrument otherwise your readings will also be funky.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes - I was referring to using the mic for the OP's acoustic guitar - it often picks up other sounds as well, confusing it.

Comment: @WheatWilliams - I stand corrected, this is the first electric tuner I have seen that apparently transposes. That said, I **do not** appreciate being patronized - as a composer and professor, I *certainly* know my instruments and their transpositions, among other things.

Comment: Sorry, @jjmusicnotes, I was not intending to be patronizing. I was just as surprised as you to find out that this tuner, while sold by the Warwick bass guitar company and labeled "Rocktuner" actually seems to be designed for transposing orchestral instruments. And I am neither a composer nor a professor; I'm just an avid amateur musician, so I defer to your superior knowledge.

Comment: @Wheat - thanks for the extra homework, my suggestion was only a wild guess.Interesting stuff. Well done ! Can't help asking - what patronising ?

Comment: I made a couple of comments that jjmusicnotes thought were patronizing to him, and I apologised and deleted them. All this happened during StackExchange being taken down by a DDoS attack yesterday, so even getting to the site and adding comments was difficult.

Comment: I had to look up some info on transposing instruments to write my answer here. I have only ever been a singer who plays a bit of guitar and even less piano, and I have never worked with a transposing innstrument myself, although I have done some copyist work on orchestral scores that require taking this into account.

Comment: @WheatWilliams Sorry, I forgot to answer. It appeared that the battery was near dead. When I changed the battery, it become functioning properly. But your answer was extremely helpful to figure out how to use the tuner, so I'm marking it. Thanks!